Show that a domain with $C^2$ boundary is strictly Levi psuedoconvex at a special boundary point.
We let $D \subset\subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be a domain with $C^2$ boundary and let $P \in bD$. We also suppose that there is some neighborhood $U$ of $P$, $v \in C^2(U)$ strictly plurisubharmonic, with $v(P) = 0$ and $v(z) < 0$ for $z \in D \cap U$. I want to show that $D$ is strictly Levi pseudoconvex at $P$.
This is the second part of a question from Range's Holomorphic Functions and Integral Representations in Several Complex Variables, problem [2.2.14.b]. I have a solution for the first part of the question here.
Unfortunately, I cannot see how my approach to the first question might help here, as I heavily relied on the strict convexity of the ball at points in its boundary, and I do not see another way to procede. Any pointers/directions would be much appreciated.
